# How to subsititute a property name in an angularjs expression with a string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

Given a set of columns specified by a user. Which will be contained within displayColumns i.e. ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'] i want to iterate over this set of values to provide me with the correct reference to each value in the model.

I don't know what the syntax is for substituting the column name into an expression so that when angular compiles it, it would look like -> {{device.name.value1.value.value}} ... I've tried [] but that obviously didn't work!

```
    <tbody md-body>
      <tr md-row ng-repeat="device in $ctrl.devices track by device.mRID">
        <td md-cell ng-click="$ctrl.detailedView($event, device)">{{device.aliasName}}</td>
        <td md-cell>{{device.mRID}}</td>
        <td md-cell ng-repeat="column in $ctrl.displayColumns">{{device.name.[column].value.value}} {{device.name.[column].unit.symbol}}<td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
{{device.name[column].value.value}} {{device.name[column].unit.sybmol}}
```

Not this:

```
{{device.name.[column].value.value}} {{device.name.[column].unit.sybmol}}
```